# how to convert .obj to to .coff (in cygwin platform)

Tags: linux, cygwin, binutils, coff, objcopy

Facing problem to convert .obj to .coff file using objcopy command.
Currently i am trying to solve this issue by using OBJCOPY Command.
i tried Command **objcopy -I input.O -O output.**
output which will be get converted to **COFF format** and input is in **.O object** format.
But it's not working.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not working?

Comment: I don't Know Why it's not working....

Comment: This isn't really enough information to say what is wrong.  If by ".obj" file you mean something made with "gcc -c", then you need to link your program, not use objcopy.